# Cassandra Hadoop map reduce with wide rows ignores slice predicate

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, thrift

I have a wide row column family which Im trying to run a map reduce job against. The CF is a time ordered collection of events, where the column names are essentially timestamps. I need to run the MR job against a specific date range in the CF.

When I run the job with the widerow property set to false, the expected slice of columns are passed into the mapper class. But when I set widerow to true, the entire column family is processed, ignoring the slice predicate.

The problem is that I have to use widerow support, as the number of columns in the slice can grow very large and consume all the memory if loaded in one go.

I've found this JIRA task which outlines the issue, but it has been closed off as "cannot reproduce" - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4871?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel

Im running cassandra 1.2.6 and using cassandra-thrift 1.2.4 & hadoop-core 1.1.2 in my jar. The CF has been created using CQL3.

Its worth noting that this occurs regardless of whether I use a SliceRange or specify the columns using setColumn_names() - it still process all of the columns.

Any help will be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that this is by design. In the word_count example in github, the following comment  exists:

```
// this will cause the predicate to be ignored in favor of scanning everything as a wide row
ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KEYSPACE, COLUMN_FAMILY, true);
```

Urrrrgh. Fair enough then. It seems crazy that there is no way to limit the columns when using wide rows though.

**UPDATE**

Apparently the solution is to use the new apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3 library. See the new example on github for reference: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/examples/hadoop_cql3_word_count/src/WordCount.java

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, to add the comment as answer but we are trying to do same thing but you mentioned that you are able to that "When I run the job with the widerow property set to false, the expected slice of columns are passed into the mapper class. " but when we set widerow property set to false we are still getting we are getting errors. How did you pass the timestamp range in the slice predicate.

The CF that we use is a timeline of events with uid as partition key and event_timestamp as composite column. The equivalent cql is,

CREATE TABLE testcf (
uid varchar, 
evennt_timestamp timestamp, 
event varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (uid, event_timestamp));

Map reduce code – to send only events within start and end dates (note : we can query from the cassandra-client and cqlsh on the timestamp composite column and get the desired events)

```
// Settting widerow to false
        config.setInputColumnFamily(Constants.KEYSPACE_TRACKING, Constants.CF_USER_EVENTS, false); 
DateTime start = getStartDate(); // e.g., July 30th 2013  
        DateTime end = getEndDate();   // e.g., Aug 6th 2013

        SliceRange range = new SliceRange(
ByteBufferUtil.bytes(start.getMillis()),  
ByteBufferUtil.bytes(end.getMillis()), 
false, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
   SlicePredicate predicate = new SlicePredicate().setSlice_range(range);
   config.setInputSlicePredicate(predicate);


 But the above code doesn't work. We get the following error,
java.lang.RuntimeException: InvalidRequestException(why:Invalid bytes remaining after an end-of-component at component0)
at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$StaticRowIterator.maybeInit(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:384)
```

Wondering if we are sending incorrect data in the start and end parameters in the slice range.

Any hint or help is useful.

Comment: In my case we use c# ticks instead of timestamps as our composite column. So the slice range is set using (pseudo code) range.setStart("634926384000000000".getBytes()); I assume if you set the range start and end to be an empty byte array it works fine?